# Java having a image reappear once off screen

Tags: java

I am kind of stuck on this issue.

Basically I have a car image that I need to have go back to the start point once it disappers off the screen on the x axis. I thought I had it fixed by my checkOFFscreen but it did not work so I am suck and asking for some guidance on how to solve this.

**Mainpanel.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    Player myPlayer;
    Player myOtherPlayer;
    private int WIDTH = 1000;
    private int HEIGHT = 1000;
    private int WALLWIDTH = 100;
    private int WALLHEIGHT = 100;
    private ArrayList<Wall> walls = new ArrayList<Wall>();


    Timer myTimer = new Timer(500, new timerListener());    
    JLabel myTimeLabel;
    int time =1;



    public MainPanel()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
        JLabel myLabel= new JLabel ("Game ends once 30 seconds is receahed:");
        myLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD,32));
        myLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        myTimeLabel= new JLabel (Integer.toString(time));
        myTimeLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD,32));
        myTimer.start();

        add(myLabel);
        add(myTimeLabel);
        myPlayer = new Player(0,100, "toad.png", KeyEvent.VK_UP, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT,this, 50, 38);
        myOtherPlayer = new Player(200,200, "toad.png", KeyEvent.VK_W, KeyEvent.VK_S, KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.VK_D,this, 50, 38);
        createWalls();
    }

    public ArrayList<Wall> getWalls() {
        return walls;
    }

    public void createWalls()
    {
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT/WALLHEIGHT; i++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < WIDTH/WALLWIDTH; k++)
            {
                if(i == 0 || i == (HEIGHT/WALLHEIGHT-1))
                {
                    walls.add(new Wall(k*WALLWIDTH,j,"road.png", 100, 100));
                }

            }
            j+=WALLHEIGHT;
        }
    }


    private class timerListener implements ActionListener
    {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            time++;
            myTimeLabel.setText(Integer.toString(time));
            myTimeLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            if(time >= 30)
            {
                myTimer.stop();
            }
            repaint();
        }

    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
    {
        super.paintComponent(page);

        page.drawImage(myPlayer.getImageIcon().getImage(), myPlayer.getX(), myPlayer.getY(), null);
        page.drawImage(myOtherPlayer.getImageIcon().getImage(), myOtherPlayer.getX(), myOtherPlayer.getY(), null);

        for(int i = 0; i < walls.size(); i++)
        {
            page.drawImage(walls.get(i).getImageIcon().getImage(), walls.get(i).getX(), walls.get(i).getY(), null);


        }

        page.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN,32)); 
        page.drawString("Player 1 Score: " + myPlayer.getScore(), 100, 800);
        page.drawString("Player 2 Score: " + myOtherPlayer.getScore(), 100, 850);


        if(time > 30)
        {
            page.drawString("GAME OVER", WIDTH/2-100, HEIGHT/2);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter your email");

            }

    }
}
```

**Player.java**

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Player extends GameObject implements KeyListener{


    private int Up;
    private int Down;
    private int Left;
    private int Right;

    private MainPanel myPanel;
    private Movement myMovement = new Movement();

    private int score = 0;

    public Player(int x, int y, String imagePath, int Up, int Down, int Left, int Right, MainPanel myPanel, int HEIGHT, int WIDTH)
    {
        super(x,y,imagePath, HEIGHT, WIDTH);

        this.Up = Up;
        this.Down = Down;
        this.Left = Left;
        this.Right = Right;
        this.myPanel = myPanel;
        myPanel.addKeyListener(this);
        myPanel.setFocusable(true);
         checkOffScreen();

    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void checkOffScreen(){
        if (x >=1050){
            x=0;
        }
    }



    public int getScore()
    {
        return score;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int key = arg0.getKeyCode();

        if(key == Left)
        {
            x-=myMovement.getDistanceLeft();
            if(checkWalls())
            {
                x+=10;
            }
        }
        else if(key == Right)
        {
            x+=myMovement.getDistanceRight();
            if(checkWalls())
            {
                x-=10;
            }
        }


        myPanel.repaint();

    }

    public boolean checkWalls()
    {
        ArrayList<Wall> walls = myPanel.getWalls();

        for(int i = 0 ; i < walls.size(); i++)
        {
            if(areRectsColliding(x,x+HEIGHT,y,y+WIDTH,walls.get(i).getX(), walls.get(i).getX()+ walls.get(i).getHEIGHT(),
                    walls.get(i).getY(),walls.get(i).getY()+walls.get(i).getWIDTH()))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
        }
        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private boolean areRectsColliding(int r1TopLeftX, int r1BottomRightX,
            int r1TopLeftY, int r1BottomRightY, int r2TopLeftX,
            int r2BottomRightX, int r2TopLeftY, int r2BottomRightY) {

        if (r1TopLeftX < r2BottomRightX && r1BottomRightX > r2TopLeftX
                && r1TopLeftY < r2BottomRightY && r1BottomRightY > r2TopLeftY) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ImageIcon getImageIcon() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new ImageIcon(imagePath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

checkOffScreen looks like it's in your initialization of the player, not the main loop of the game. You need to check the x when you repaint, just like when you're moving the image of the car, every time you call to move the image of the car, you need to check your x axis after it's been moved.
Pseudo code

```
Player.checkOffScreen();
myPanel.repaint();
```

This should move the car back to the beginning after it's reached the parameters given.

Comment: Ok so I add the my.Panel.repaint to the checkOffScreen since what you said bad sense. There nothing "repaint" img back in its original area. However it did not seem to work. Did I do it correctly?  public void checkOffScreen(){
  if (x >=500){
   x=0;
   myPanel.repaint();

  }
 }

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific. In your main panel. Call the player that has the x. So you have your function checkOffScreen. You need to call that for the player you are checking. So you have two players that are initialized myPlayer and myOtherPlayer. You need access that function within your main loop before repainting. So if you were checking to see if myPlayer was off screen. You would call myPlayer.checkOffScreen(); then repaint.

Comment: I'm trying to be a bit ambiguous and not just give you the code outright, that's how coders learn. :) It needs to go in your Mainpanel.java and you need to call myPlayer.checkOffScreen() and myOtherPlayer.checkOffScreen() in your main loop.

Comment: Ok thanks I got it to work. I appericate the vagueness though I did learn here. I am just not super confident with graphcial programs still,

Comment: Sure thing! Java can be a little weird at times when it comes to graphical stuff, but practice makes perfect. Glad you got it working.